# How can I briefly flash a rectangle around a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is when a user clicks something:

```
<div id="FormContainer">
    <form>
     ...
    </form>
</div>

<a href="#" onClick="FlashElement()">Make it flash</a>
```

It briefly flashes a rectangle around the form within the `FormContainer`. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: If you are using jQuery just use the animate method to animate the colour from something to its normal colour so it looks like flashing.

Comment: Could you use js / jquery to put a border on the element - vs a transparent or white border? There are plugins that animate color I know if you have to fade it.

Comment: @Francisc: jQuery does not animate colors out of the box. He would also need the jQueryUI in order to make that work. Just for this simple task this is total overkill and he would do best to write a little animate function himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and simple way would be to draw a colored border then remove it after a short period:

```javascript
function FlashElement() {
  var $el=$('#FormContainer'), oldBorder=$el.css('border');
  $el.css({border:'4px solid yellow'});
  setTimeout(function() { $el.css({border:oldBorder}); }, 500);
}
```

If you want a repeated flashing effect then you could make several calls to "setTimeout" to hide/show the border at the desired interval, e.g.:

```javascript
  // ...
  var newBorder = '4px solid yellow';
  $el.css({border:newBorder});
  setTimeout(function() { $el.css({border:oldBorder}); }, 100);
  setTimeout(function() { $el.css({border:newBorder}); }, 200);
  setTimeout(function() { $el.css({border:oldBorder}); }, 300);
  setTimeout(function() { $el.css({border:newBorder}); }, 400);
  setTimeout(function() { $el.css({border:oldBorder}); }, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `animate` function combined with the "color" plugin. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mostthingsweb/wjDJm/4/

**HTML:**

```
<div>my content</div>

<br/>
<button id='button'>Click me</button>​
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}​
```

**JS:**

```
function makeColors(color){
    return {
        borderTopColor: color,
        borderBottomColor: color,
        borderRightColor: color,
        borderLeftColor: color
    }
}

$("#button").click(function() {
    $("div").stop().animate(makeColors("red"), 1000, function(){
       $(this).animate(makeColors("transparent"), 500);         
    });
});​
```

Notes:

- An initial transparent border is created via CSS to prevent the element from "jumping" which would be the case when a 1px border is suddenly added.
- Requires the color plugin: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Answer (score 1):

use [this plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) and the following code and [here's the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9NE4y/2/)

```
$(function() {
    $('div').on('click', function() {
        $el = $(this);
        $el.css({border:'1px solid #FFF'});
        $el.animate({
            'borderColor': '#F00'
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            $el.animate({
                'borderColor': '#FFF'
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
});​
```